# Error while writing from bag file to csv

Tags: ros, bagfiles, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I'm trying to extract data from a bag file and save it into a csv. For this I've been using:

```
rostopic echo -p --nosstr --noarr -b bagfile.bag /topic > name.csv
```

But now I also want to filter the data before storing it into the csv file. I've checked [rostopic echo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rostopic) and found that it has a filter command. I've tried to use it:

```
rostopic echo --filter "m.header.stamp.secs>=1342763900 and m.header.stamp.secs name.csv
```

And got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/bin/rostopic", line 45, in 
    rostopic.rostopicmain()
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rostopic/src/rostopic.py", line 1696, in rostopicmain
    _rostopic_cmd_echo(argv)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rostopic/src/rostopic.py", line 1041, in _rostopic_cmd_echo
    _rostopic_echo(topic, callback_echo, bag_file=options.bag)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rostopic/src/rostopic.py", line 689, in _rostopic_echo
    _rostopic_echo_bag(callback_echo, bag_file)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rostopic/src/rostopic.py", line 670, in _rostopic_echo_bag
    callback_echo.callback(msg, t, current_time=timestamp)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rostopic/src/rostopic.py", line 577, in callback
    if self.filter_fn is not None and not self.filter_fn(data):
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rostopic/src/rostopic.py", line 967, in eval_fn
    return eval(expr)
  File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: '_std_msgs__String' object has no attribute 'header'
```

But if instead of trying to save the data to a csv I just do the rostopic echo with the filter while a rosbag play is publishing the messages I have no problem.

Can somebody help please??

Cheers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41238/error-while-writing-from-bag-file-to-csv/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2012-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That sounds like a bug to me.

Probably the best solution is to [open a defect ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/newticket?component=ros_comm&type=defect&&ros_comm), to be sure the rosbag maintainers see it.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0